# Wait for image to disappear by using pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

In using pyautogui to check if an image is not part of the screen, I tried below:

```
a = True
while a is True:
    a = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png')
print ("No this image.')
```

It doesn't seem work well.

What's the proper way to do so?

Comment: Does it throw any error??

Comment: From the [documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions):

"`locateOnScreen(image, grayscale=False)` Returns (left, top, width, height) coordinate of first found instance of the `image` on the screen. Raises `ImageNotFoundException` if not found on the screen."

However, from your code, it seems like you are expecting it to return a `bool`.

Comment: @Anwarvic, no it doesn't.

Comment: @m-alorda, thank you for looking into the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Putting it a `for` loop to continuosly check the presence of the image, once it disappeared, quit the loop.

```py
for _ in range(100):
    time.sleep(1)
    a = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png')
    if a == None:
        print('No this image.')
        break
```